# Create a floating horizontal scroll bar for an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame. If a user zooms in or uses high magnification due to bad eyesight, I want a horizontal scroll bar to appear so that the user can scroll left to right within the iFrame. This part is easy and not an issue. The problem I've found is that the scroll bar appears at the bottom of the iFrame, which, if zoomed in enough to need it, would require the user to scroll very far down from the actual content to use it, which isn't user friendly.

What I want is for a scroll bar to be visible at the bottom of the visible window that is linked to the main scroll bar, and would be a bonus if it disappears if the user does scroll down enough to see the main scroll bar.

I should reiterate that this is inside an iFrame where the content is cross-domain. I can edit the content in the iFrame but it would be a fairly large task to do that, whereas editing the main window is relatively simple, so would be nice if all the work required could be done in there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option you have is to control the scroll with the mouse wheel, see example https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/5gs8pojm/

```
(function() {
function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
} else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
}
})();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how this works? I'm not sure I understand fully, but it looks to me like this overrides the normal mouse scroll functionality (which is vertical) and changes it to horizontal. While that could work for my purposes (I'd need to check with others), it seems that it could also present other problems such as the inability to scroll vertically.

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth I built a fiddle inside a fiddle to show you how it would work, the scroll bar on the right will be moved manually and the bottom will use the wheel, (reversed the rolls). the blue background area is the test area https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/5gs8pojm/6/

Comment: Is there anyway to activate this only when the horizontal scroll bar is present?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use a bit more Javascript to do it. I can write it a little later